# How to increase accuracy in CNN?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am a newbie to CNNs, but do possess a basic understanding of ML and Neural Networks.

I wanted to create my own CNN that works on the Cats and Dogs Dataset. I preprocessed the data and built my network, but when I fit the model with the data, I am not able to get more than 55% accuracy, which means the model isn't learning anything.

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong here?

Already tried varying learning rates, and even dropout, but in vain

The Data processing part:

```
train_directory = r'C:\Users\atjayade\Downloads\P14-Convolutional-Neural-Networks\Convolutional_Neural_Networks\dataset\training_set'

test_directory = r'C:\Users\atjayade\Downloads\P14-Convolutional-Neural-Networks\Convolutional_Neural_Networks\dataset\test_set'

def label_image(img):
    label = img.split('.')[-3]
    if label == 'cat':
        return [1,0]
    if label == 'dog':
        return [0,1]

training=[]

for item1 in os.listdir(train_directory):
    path1 = os.path.join(train_directory, item1)
    for item in tqdm.tqdm(os.listdir(path1)):
        lab = label_image(item)
        img_path = os.path.join(path1, item)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (50,50))
        training.append([np.array(img), lab])

testing=[]

for item1 in os.listdir(test_directory):
    path1 = os.path.join(test_directory, item1)
    for item in tqdm.tqdm(os.listdir(path1)):
        lab = label_image(item)
        img_path = os.path.join(path1, item)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (50,50))
        testing.append([np.array(img), lab])

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in testing]).reshape(-1,50,50,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in testing]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in training]).reshape(-1,50,50,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in training]
```

And the CNN model and optimizer part:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='SAME', input_shape=X[0].shape))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), dim_ordering='th'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.4))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='SAME'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), dim_ordering='th'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.35))

#model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='SAME'))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.3))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X, np.array(Y), validation_data=(test_x, np.array(test_y)), epochs=30, verbose=2)
```

The above model , when run, does not give accuracy more than 50%. TRied different variations of CNN builts, different optimizers, but in vain.

Is there something that I am not seeing?

Comment: For instance, your loss should be 'categorical_crossentropy'.

Comment: There are only two classes. Cats and Dogs. binary_crossentropy should work fine, right?

Comment: I believe this dataset is discussed in: https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks-tensorflow/home/welcome. You may consider doing the free trial.

Comment: I did see that trial online. But I wanted to know why this CNN is not working.

Comment: You have selected a 'softmax' activation. That should go along with categorical_cross entropy. Or 'sigmoid' activation with 'binary' loss, if you want to allow for the possibility of an image having neither of the classes or both.

Comment: Identical results in both cases. Accuracy doesn't go above 60%

Comment: Try dividing your image arrays by `255.` (img / 255.) to normalize?

Comment: Did you try using other optimizers, and tuning their learning rates? The current learning rate you use might be too low.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally.

After tweaking and playing around with so many different learning rates and optimizers, and other parameters, I've found that Adadelta with the default learning rate is most suited for this.

Thank you everyone for trying to help me.

Cheers.